# Screen magnifier that also shows mousepointer

Tags: mouse, accessibility, mouse-pointer

Is there a magnifier application for Ubuntu similar to `xzoom` but which would also show the mouse pointer in the magnified area?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something close to `xzoom` which also shows the mouse cursor is `kmag`:

```
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends kmag
```

Use <kbd>F6</kbd> to toggle between a hidden and visible mouse cursor.

---

[image]